# Why do I need to provide method implementation when I extend a protocol in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to extend some protocol, while writing the code compiler throws error: `please provide implementation of method`. But why do I have to provide implementation of protocol method? This should be done in the class which conforms to this protocol.

```
extension MyDelegate { 
    func addNewMethod() { } 
} 

protocol MyDelegate { 
     func myMethod() 
}
```

Comment: Please show the code and details of the error

Comment: extension MyDelegate {
        func addNewMethod(){
    }
}

protocol MyDelegate {
    func myMethod()
}

Comment: required , optional
There are two types of protocol , By default all the required protocols are must implemented.

Comment: You should *edit* your question to show the code there

Answer (score 0):

it seems [according to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521) that protocol extensions only exist to give existing protocols default implementations of methods, so that not every class that uses the protocol has to implement the same method and have the same body, saving you a lot of copy pasting, sort of like a static/class function for the protocol

it sounds like you dont want an extension, but rather an optional function in the original protocol

Comment: I don't know if that is the only reason the protocol extensions exist, but the documentation is a little misleading.  It implies that default implementations are optional, but in fact they appear to be mandatory.  This makes sense when you think about it; if you didn't provide a default implementation then other classes that adopted the protocol and were ignorant of your extension wouldn't have a method which is now part of the protocol

Comment: @Paulw11 thats true, the documentation doesnt really show any other uses for it though so not sure what else you could do with it, and my answer is just based off what i could see in the docs heh

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to be Apple's best effort

Comment: @Paulw11 seems to be a decent example in this [wwdc video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/?time=1927) at 32min

Comment: although at the end of the day it just is a default implementation of a protocol again, so could be all it can do really